# How can I improve the efficiency of my JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, performance

I'm familiar with JavaScript basics, but I'm trying to become more efficient with my code.  To practice, I made a program that generates the Fibonacci sequence.  This is my JavaScript code:

```
let currentDigit = 1;
let lastDigit = 0;
let text = document.getElementById('numbers');


for (i = 0; i<=30; i++) {
    let temp = currentDigit;
    text.innerHTML += " " + currentDigit;
    if(i !== 30) {
        text.innerHTML += ","
    }
    currentDigit += lastDigit;
    lastDigit = temp;
}
```

What improvements can I make on this for it to be cleaner, more efficient, and faster?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xpKyMy)

Comment: Don't append to innerHTML; it makes the browser re-parse.

Comment: @Will in the future, please don't use Code Review as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *too broad*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see the section **What you should not do** in [this answer to _A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: While it is better-suited for Code Review, that doesn't make it off-topic here, per se.

Comment: How about e.g. `const fibonacci = (n0, n1) => () => n1 = n0 + (n0 = n1); Array.from({length: 30}, fibonacci(0, 1)).join(', ')`?

Answer (score 2):

(See **Update** for more efficient approach)

While this is not necessarily faster, it does allow for a separation of concerns and is definitely a cleaner approach. That is, using [a generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator):

```js
function * fibonacci (length, curr = 1, last = 0) {
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    yield curr;
    [curr, last] = [curr + last, curr];
  }
}

let text = document.getElementById('numbers');

text.append(Array.from(fibonacci(31)).join(', '));
```

```html
<div id="numbers"></div>
```

Just to clarify though, generator functions are generally not considered an optimized approach, as there's a lot of overhead to allow operations like [`yield`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) and [`yield*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*).

Another point I can add regarding DOM manipulation is to [create a text node and `append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) it to the `#numbers` element rather than causing the browser to completely re-parse the element as [@SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47758899/1541563#comment82479042_47758899) pointed out. Doing so *is* indeed more efficient.

#### Update

Playing off of [@le_m's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47758899/1541563#comment82479784_47758899), this would also work:

```js
function fibonacci (length, next = 1, curr = 0) {
  const mapFn = () => {
    [next, curr] = [next + curr, next];
    return curr;
  };

  return Array.from({ length }, mapFn);
}

let text = document.getElementById('numbers');

text.append(fibonacci(31).join(', '));
```

```html
<div id="numbers"></div>
```

Comment: How about `text.textContent += ...`?

Comment: @le_m that would still cause a re-parse, though that does prevent some types of XSS attacks, unlike the usage of `innerHTML`.

Comment: Just looked it up: setting `textContent` replaces all nodes within the element with a single new text node according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) - so it might be equally fast, but I never tested it.

Comment: @le_m that's _setting_, not _concatenating_. i.e. `=` vs. `+=`.

Comment: Great job Patrick!  But why do you need the {} around length?  `return Array.from({ length }, mapFn);`  The output is blank without them but I'm not sure what they are doing.

Comment: @DR01D in ES6, `{ length }` is an object literal shorthand for `{ length: length }`, since the variable name matches the property it's being assigned to in the literal.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts You're absolutely right I didn't catch that!  I thought the curly brackets were some new, innovative way to pass in arguments.  haha

Answer (score 1):

Here's an optimized version of your code, depending on how well destructuring assignment is optimized in the engine you're running.

```
let a = 0;
let b = 1;
text.append(" ", Array.from(Array(31), () => [a,b] = [b,a+b], a).join(", "));
```

```js
let currentDigit = 1;
let lastDigit = 0;
let text = document.getElementById('numbers');

for (i = 0; i<=30; i++) {
    let temp = currentDigit;
    text.innerHTML += " " + currentDigit;
    if(i !== 30) {
        text.innerHTML += ","
    }
    currentDigit += lastDigit;
    lastDigit = temp;
}


text = document.getElementById('numbers2');
let a = 0;
let b = 1;
text.append(" ", Array.from(Array(31), () => ([a,b] = [b,a+b], a)).join(", "));
```

```html
<pre id=numbers>Your version:</pre>
<pre id=numbers2>New version:</pre>
```

---

Or with a `for-of` loop, again depending on optimizations.

```
let a = 0;
let b = 1;
let arr = Array(31);
for (const i of arr.keys()) {
  arr[i] = ([a,b] = [b,a+b], a);
}
text.append(" ", arr.join(", "));
```

```js
let currentDigit = 1;
let lastDigit = 0;
let text = document.getElementById('numbers');

for (i = 0; i<=30; i++) {
    let temp = currentDigit;
    text.innerHTML += " " + currentDigit;
    if(i !== 30) {
        text.innerHTML += ","
    }
    currentDigit += lastDigit;
    lastDigit = temp;
}


text = document.getElementById('numbers2');
let a = 0;
let b = 1;
let arr = Array(31);
for (const i of arr.keys()) {
  arr[i] = ([a,b] = [b,a+b], a);
}
text.append(" ", arr.join(", "));
```

```html
<pre id=numbers>Your version:</pre>
<pre id=numbers2>New version:</pre>
```

Comment: Any significant difference between `Array.from(Array(31), ...)` and `Array.from({length: 31}, ...)`?

Comment: @le_m: Nah, both objects are going to be discarded, both are sparse, and both have been around since the beginning so will likely be highly optimized.